# Heroku application error after many database requests

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, heroku, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy React + Node (with typescript) as a free Heroku web app. I use ClearDB MySQL (also free add-on).

Everything works good and there is no problem with the app until I have too many requests to the database. I am just getting info from the database (SELECT). When I do it few times (approximately 10 times during the server is not sleeping), the next requests on the database will crash. After a refresh of the page, it is also not possible to load the page correctly. It only shows Application Error. I see H10 error in error logs.

Is it a problem with a type of server and database? I mean that it's free, so it will crash after some requests. If it is not this type of problem, does anybody have ideas what to do? If you need some more specific info, I will provide it.

**EDIT:** It is because Connection do database is lost. Heroku used to shut down the app when there are many errors in a row. So question is, how to solve Connection loss.

I also provide error log:

```
2021-08-30T11:25:45.178960+00:00 app[web.1]: > api@1.0.0 start 
2021-08-30T11:25:45.178960+00:00 app[web.1]: > ts-node server.ts 
2021-08-30T11:25:45.178961+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-30T11:25:49.764096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up 
2021-08-30T11:25:49.701827+00:00 app[web.1]: APP running on port 26858 
2021-08-30T11:26:01.705662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/message" host=random-messenger.herokuapp.com request_id=1fac5c60-c66c-425a-acb4-17f173b72870 fwd="188.167.229.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=81ms status=200 bytes=309 protocol=https 
2021-08-30T11:26:02.705066+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/message" host=random-messenger.herokuapp.com request_id=56879ea0-382d-42ca-b757-ed1d6e4d5137 fwd="188.167.229.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=361 protocol=https 
2021-08-30T11:26:03.599888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/message" host=random-messenger.herokuapp.com request_id=8f8fa4ef-0535-4cdd-abbd-6f93eeae0941 fwd="188.167.229.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=312 protocol=https 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.162648+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.162660+00:00 app[web.1]: var err = new Error('Connection lost: The server closed the connection.'); 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.162661+00:00 app[web.1]: ^ 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164283+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164284+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164284+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28) 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164285+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10) 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164286+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:406:35) 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164286+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12) 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164286+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1331:12) 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164286+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) { 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164287+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true, 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164287+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.164287+00:00 app[web.1]: } 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.316331+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed 
2021-08-30T11:27:01.228791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-30T11:28:17.001351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/receive" host=random-messenger.herokuapp.com request_id=a5d2639a-b804-4706-bc75-ed236fbbaa25 fwd="188.167.229.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
2021-08-30T11:28:17.461640+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=random-messenger.herokuapp.com request_id=78e7a216-d0c3-4c7f-928b-b10ae7dff3ae fwd="188.167.229.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**SOLUTION FROM @Molda**
The free ClearDB addon only allows 10 connections. My fault was that I did not reuse Connection and create new every time. Now it works! Thank you everybody for help.

Comment: have you checked  the error log for hints?

Comment: Yes. There are some errors. Most of them are code=H10....but I also see now, when I scroll up, that there is some Connection lost to the database. I know that Heroku shuts down the web app when there are many errors in a row. When there is a Connection lost and I continue with database requests, there are more H10 errors and then the app crashes. But question is....why is Connection lost? Its only when I do few database requests in a row. It's not like the connection is lost after some time from starting the app.

Comment: post the sanitized error log, the app crashes because you don't have a proper error handling wit try catch

Comment: Thank you for helping, I edited my question and add an error log.

Comment: The free ClearDB addon only allows 10 connections. Do you reuse the connection or create a new one for each of the requests?

Comment: @Molda no I do not reuse it, I create always new ones. Thank you very much ! This helps a lot ! This must be a problem because it always falls after 10 requests in a row.

Comment: @MatejPeluha  What did you change to 'reuse connections'?

Comment: @WilsonHauck In Nodejs, I have one "config" module for the database connection. It was exporting function which was creating a MySQL connection. I called this function in my service classes. When I think now after fixing, it is not good practice to create a new connection every time I have a request on the database. My fix was simple. Now my "config" module is not exporting function, but I create a connection once in the module, and I am exporting just the connection as an object. Every time I import it from that module, it is still the same connection.

Comment: Thank you for the Nodejs pointer for your change to be effective.

Comment: @MatejPeluha have a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections Using the connections pool you can open 10(or any number you choose) connections and reuse every one of them.